# php compare value in every array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below:

```
$number = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

I have a value like below:

```
$my_num = 2;
```

I want to compare $my_num variable in every $number array.
My expected output like this: No, Yes, No, No, No.

I tried like this:

```
<?php
if(in_array($my_num, $number))
{
    echo 'Yes';
}
else
{
    echo 'No';
}
```

But I can only get 'Yes' from above output.
How should I modify it in order to get my expected output?

Comment: you need a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 3):

Like I said in the comment above, all you need is a `foreach` to iterate through your array and compare your data.

```
foreach($numbers as $num){
    echo ($num == $my_num) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3):

Here's one [option](https://eval.in/427184), essentially comparing `$my_num` to each array value and mapping it to a Yes or No. The commas are for your expected result only.

```
$english = array_map(function($val) use ($my_num) {
    return ($val == $my_num) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}, $number);
echo implode(', ', $english); // No, Yes, No, No, No
```

Comment: Agree mostly :) if you want to format it though (e.g. as the example with commas) then this method might save you having to built another array and implode that later

Comment: @Dagon I'll bet you say that to all your neighbours ;-)

Comment: Seems like someone's going around downvoting perfectly good answers, I got one at probably the same time. Lovely. Can you hear that "slithering" sound?

Comment: @Fred-ii- lucky he lives a few thousand km and an island away.

Comment: Appreciate the chat, but the comments probably aren't relevant unless you're using Google Maps API to determine them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a foreach loop. It loops through the array assigning the value of the current array member to the variable $num.

```
foreach ($number as $num) {
    if ($num == $my_num) {
        echo 'Yes';
    } else {
        echo 'No';
    }
}
```